# boot menu in aspire one 725

Tags: boot

can you tell me how to enter boot menu on startup
so I can install ubuntu 12.10 
on aspire there is a grub menu and kernel installed but my skills are not good enough to do anything with it

Comment: Can you give more details by editing your question? Is Windows installed? Where did the GRUB menu and kernel come from? What choices do the GRUB menu give you? What happens when you select these choices? By **boot menu** do you mean the BIOS or the GRUB menu?

Comment: No i bought it and they told me linux was installed on I thought ok
when i booted it it shows me grub 0.97 and kernel 3.15 that is it
I entered bios and enabled boot menu and when I press but usb stick it just starts grub menu

Comment: sorry for not giving ton of information, there was Linpus Linux installed on it I deleted it with commend
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=512 count=1
but now i Can not boot ubuntu 12.10 from usb sadly it does not have cd drive 

 it tells me no bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem I had usb formatted as ntfs and not fat took a fat32 usb stick and It worked great